# Python framework vs api vs REST api

Tags: python, api, visual-studio-code, frameworks, python-3.8

As I'm not sure, where to start programmatically speaking, I'll give you a shortcut of what I want to achieve:
Right now, I have multiple small programms, with which data can be processed and manipulated in certain ways. I.e. one program does some Fourier transformation, another does some normalisation etc.
What I want/need to do is, to build a python software with a GUI in that way, that any user can take his data and choose by e.g. a dropdown menu (I'm not sure yet), how the data is going to be processed. My program then should use one of these beforementioned tiny programs, process it and deliver the wished output.
I have read about frameworks, API, REST api etc. But I'm confused, what is the best way. Btw, I'm using python 3.8 with VS code.
Any longterm tipps would be awesome as well!

Answer (score 1):

I'd pick Flask.

Why?

- smooth learning curve
- easy to be maintained
- easy to deploy (heroku, pythonanywhere, etc.)
- super-active community (discord, reddit, etc.)

You can generate a template.html page and then replicate the UI in other areas of the website you are creating.

You can easily import all your functions as if they were modules.

You can create UI within minutes.

This simple snippet allows you to render an html page (main.html) where you can return Python functions or even variables to use in the code.

```
from flask import Flask, request, render_template

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config["DEBUG"] = True

@app.route('/', methods = ["GET"])
def input_page():
    return render_template("main.html")
    
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(use_reloader=False)
```

[Flask Documentation](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.0.x/)